# My website has an SSL certificate on Heroku but appears not secure

Tags: heroku

I have a SSL on heroku and when I go to https://www.example.com appears secure but when I go to example.com ( which redirects to https://www.example.com from names.co.uk ) appears not secure I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you remove the redirect and set the canonical (example.com) as a CNAME in your DNS settings.

Your problem is due to the redirect.

Comment: I already have on DNS settings: www CNAME www.example.com.herokudns.com. As heroku doesn't supports naked domains I've set the redirect.

Comment: Does this help you?
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: Those are my settings and I did as heroku said but still not use the SSL certificate, only if type manually https in the front.

Comment: I'm just testing on my own account. Waiting for changes to propagate.

Comment: Ah. You could try to set "refresh to forwarding URL" and see if that doesn't solve it. ('...issue-3' image)

Comment: I've tried that but at the moment it doesn't work, it might needs time to update it. If not I think the issue is with the domain provider. I will try to go through support team. Thank you Johan for your help!